# How can I register my js code in a yii2 project after inline script correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, yii2

I'm writing a small JS-library for bootstrap-collapse. I have the problem: when the page is generated using the Yii2 `Collapse` widget, at the very end of the `<body>` something like this is written:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    jQuery('#w0').collapse();
    jQuery('#w1').collapse();
    jQuery('#w2').collapse();
    jQuery('#w3').collapse();
    jQuery('#w4').collapse();
});
```

[image]

It happens because method `run` of `Collapse` widget contains the next code:

```
public function run()
    {
        //Method from BootstrapWidgetTrait
        $this->registerPlugin('collapse');
        return implode("\n", [
            Html::beginTag('div', $this->options),
            $this->renderItems(),
            Html::endTag('div')
        ]) . "\n";
    }

    //Code from BootstrapWidgetTrait
    protected function registerPlugin($name)
    {
        $view = $this->getView();

        BootstrapPluginAsset::register($view);

        $id = $this->options['id'];

        if ($this->clientOptions !== false) {
            $options = empty($this->clientOptions) ? '' : Json::htmlEncode($this->clientOptions);
            $js = "jQuery('#$id').$name($options);";
            $view->registerJs($js);
        }

        $this->registerClientEvents();
    }
```

This affects the operation of my library.
If I register my js-library using `$this->registerJsFile()`, the code will be  upper than the code registered using `$this->registerJs()`

Of course, I can also use the `$this->registerJs()` method and register my JS code at the end of the script that is created when the widget is initialized, but this method looks bad, I think. Any ideas on how to do this more correctly?

**UPD:**
I came up with such a solution:
I override the registerAssetFiles () method
in the MyJsLibraryAsset.php file as follows:

```
public function registerAssetFiles($view)
{
    parent::registerAssetFiles($view);
    $view->registerJs('funcName()');
}
```

And inside my MyLibrary.js file, I wrap all the code in the funcName () function as follows:

```
function funcName() {
    //here all my code...
}
```

It works, but it seems so bad... 
Are there other ways to solve the problem?

Comment: still trying to understand the `Collapse` widget you are talking about is the one you are creating ? and where do you want your js code to appear.

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam, thanks for your answer.  The `Collapse` widget is Yii2 widget(`yii\bootstrap\Collapse;`), not mine.
This widget creates events that affect my code. (as I wrote at the beginning of my post). All I need is for my code to be executed after the events created by the `Collapse` widget.

Comment: ok, and how are you creating your plugin do you have an `AssetManager` file from where you are registring your scripts ? please add the file if you are using one.

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam, I updated my first message. Do you mean it?
Anyway, my asset file is very simple: https://pastebin.com/BQBJHsdk

Answer (score 1):

What i understand that the plugin you are creating has the dependency on one of the bootstrap plugins named `yii\bootstrap\Collapse` and for managing any dependency for the bootstrap js components you should add the dependency in your assetManager file.

How I will manage it is I will put the custom code inside a js file and list it into the `$js` var in the AssetBundle and then add the dependency on the `yii\bootstrap\BoottrapPluginAsset` so that my js file with custom code is always loaded after the bootstrap plugin js file.

See the below class with a single CSS file and the `test.js` file which will have the custom code that you are writing

```
class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    public $css = [
        'css/site.css',
    ];
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    public $js = [
        'js/test.js',
    ];

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapPluginAsset',
    ];
}
```

Once you have all setup like above register the Asset file in the layout and then view source, you will see the files loaded like below where `test.js` will always be loaded after `bootstrap.js` file

[image]

Comment: Thanks, for your answer! The problem is that my code should be executed after last string `<script></script>` on your screenshot.  I tried to solve this problem, but I think my way is bad. Please, see the update of my first message.

Comment: @RomanAndreev sorry but I can't get anything from that update, your pastebin for the Asset bundle class shows the `my-library.js` file whereas the screengrab does not have any file loaded/listed with that name, please provide actual code with real file names, your code inside the `<script></script>` tag shows you are adding the code via view using `$this->registerJs` whereas i told in my answer that it should be inside a js file and then included via asset bundle class.